# Strange Fill Effect When Rendering Railroad Data in d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, geojson, cartography

I am getting strange results from using d3 to render a GeoJSON of railroad data. The file is very large, 38M, so I include one piece of it: https://gist.github.com/amiri/8202105.

Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/amiri/8202126

Of course the most important bit is the last lines at the bottom.

I see the shapes, but the lines are not drawn properly. Rather, there is some sort of filling going on between points of the line segments. Here is a screenshot:

http://snag.gy/n2A2W.jpg

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I converted the data to topojson to see whether that might clear up my problem, but I got the same results. Is this a CSS problem, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a style/css issue.

Try setting the fill to none on the path..

```
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-width: 1.0;
}
```

or something like that. You prob also want to add a class to the path so your css selector can be specific to the railroad path (not sure if that's what the "rail-line" class is for).

Comment: Even with that change, the paths will probably still be closed loops without a fill. Something is wrong with the svg being written.

Comment: reblace: Thank you very much! I added the style you gave me to the .rail-line class, and that did it. Wow. So simple. Thank you.

Comment: Just to correct @Lokno's comment, the fill pattern you observed matches the specs for how to fill an open-ended path: ["The fill operation fills open subpaths by performing the fill operation as if an additional "closepath" command were added to the path to connect the last point of the subpath with the first point of the subpath. Thus, fill operations apply to both open subpaths within ‘path’ elements (i.e., subpaths without a closepath command) and ‘polyline’ elements."](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperties)

Comment: I had the same problem, related to Sankey diagrams and its paths. The behavior of browser rendering is correct, but the svg standard itself is here counter-intuitive. Why would open-ended path have to be filled by default? But it is good that the question was asked. +vote for both question and answer.